# How to determine a lossless join dependency preserving decomposition

Tags: functional-dependencies, decomposition

I have a homework problem to determine a lossless join dependency decomposition for the following:

```
R(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J)
```

with the functional dependencies:

```
AB -> CG
C -> A
BD -> EF
ABC -> DEFG
G -> H
G -> I
G -> J
H -> IJ
J -> I
I -> H
```

I know the first step is to determine a minimal/canonical cover which I've done here:

```
AB -> C
C -> A
BD -> E
BD -> F
BC -> D
BC -> G
G -> J
H -> J
J -> I
I -> H
```

However I don't understand what to do after this.

I actually think this question: [Designing lossless-join, dependency preserving, 3NF database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994867/designing-lossless-join-dependency-preserving-3nf-database)
is what I am looking for but I don't understand any of the answers there. The links to the first answer are dead so I can't find the algorithm.

What are step-by-step instructions on how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you know what to do next? What is your textbook name & edition & where are you stuck in it? PS "With" FDs is not what you mean. That needs to be a *closure*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first step is to find a minimal cover. Then, you should merge dependencies which have the same left hand side. In your case, for example, `BD->E` and `BD->F` can be merged into `BD->EF`. After merging all possible dependencies in your minimal cover, each dependency can be a relation (e.g. `R1(B,D,E,F)`. Then, you get dependency preserving 3NF relations. But, it might not be lossless and you might need to convert it to a lossless scheme by adding another relation.

These are some useful resources:

- [Decomposition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xslub-nHVss&index=31&list=PLtRl4qFAP_FTWYLNSop-IDIEcbxjdLrmk)
- [Making the result lossless](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQ3ME7oOupU&index=32&list=PLtRl4qFAP_FTWYLNSop-IDIEcbxjdLrmk)
- [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34350122/5964489)